# What's the fastest way to check for similar addresses in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

A pandas DataFrame has an Address column that has potential "duplicates" where there might be an entry for `'1000 MadeUp Street'` and, `'1000 MadeUp St'`, and `'1000 Made Up Stret'`, etc.

My plan was to use fuzzywuzzy to filter through these potential duplicates and make note of those that are above a certain similarity ratio. However, looping through every row and checking every row can get ugly quickly.

What's the best/fastest way to do this?

Comment: If you have lots of memory, merge it against itself to make a frame containing every single combination. Then calculate all of your ratios on the two columns. Then select only those which match.

Comment: try `fuzzymatcher` which is much faster than fuzzy wuzzy, it needs sqllite in your python lib and java on your machine but it is very fast. read more [here](https://pbpython.com/record-linking.html)

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice , I'll check out fuzzymatcher

Comment: @ifly6 do you think this will be faster than simply looping? It'll end up being ~25million combinations